# Carousel of Images

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to create a layer of images that autoplay. Unfortunately I can't quite get it to work using multiple methods. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Here is the code that I have so far.

```js
var mItemsCount = $(".home-m-item").length - 1;

setInterval(function() {
  var t = $(".home-m-item.active");
  t.removeClass("active");
  if (t.index() === mItemsCount) {
    $(".home-m-item:first").addClass("active");
  } else {
    t.next().addClass("active");
  }
}, 200);

var windowPathname = window.location.host,
    loader = $(".loader");
```

```css
.home-m {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 0 0 200px;
    background: #111 url(assets/images/home/m-slant-bg.svg) bottom/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
        
        a, a:active, a:focus, a:hover, a:link, a:visited {
    outline: none;
}
        
    .home-m-items {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    height: calc(100% - 3px);
    z-index: 1;
}
        
    .home-m-item{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            positoin: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: 50%;
            visibility: hidden;
    }
        
        .home-m-item.active{visibility:visible}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="home-m">
    <div class="home-m-items">
      <div style="background-image: url('https://rossettibev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/R-Image-1.png');" class="home-m-item"></div>
      <div style="background-image: url('https://rossettibev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/R-Image-3.png');" class="home-m-item"></div>
      <div style="background-image: url('https://rossettibev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/R-Image-3.png');" class="home-m-item"></div>
      <div style="background-image: url('https://rossettibev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/R-Image4.png');" class="home-m-item"></div>
      <div style="background-image: url('https://rossettibev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/R-Image-5.png');" class="home-m-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm relatively new to Javscript animations, so I'm positive that this has to do with my script. I'd also be just as happy with a solution that could be achieved with keyframes as well.

Comment: I spent some time updating the formatting of your post, but the snippet you included does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. You can keep your css as it is, except that you will have to remove the `visibility:hidden` property from the item div. But I have to say your css isn't responsive. I have provided a responsive solution at the bottom. You will also need to reduce your html to the following. Here is a live demo https://codepen.io/hileamlak/pen/jOqmpmm?editors=1010

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="home-m">
        <div class="home-m-items">
            <div class="home-m-item"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your js.

```
let imageCounter = 1;

setInterval(
  ()=>{
if (imageCounter>5){imageCounter = 1;}
$(".home-m-item")[0].style.backgroundImage = `url('https://rossettibev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/R-Image-${imageCounter}.png')`;
imageCounter++;

},1000)
```

The above works as you can see in the codepen live demo, but I don't recommend using the images as a div background as it will be impossible to make your design responsive based on the size of the image so here is what I would do. https://codepen.io/hileamlak/pen/MWymBXV